# Materialize Icons working on localhost but not live

Tags: heroku, icons, materialize

I have materialize icons working on my local machine.  I can view them in both Chrome and FF.

I am calling the CDN at:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"rel="stylesheet">`

In my html I am using:

`<i class="material-icons teal-text text-accent-4">menu</i>`  (I've changed the colour)

However when looking at the site live on either desktop or mobile, I just see the 'text' relating to the icon.  I see that many others have had this problem and most say to simply add the CDN stylesheet in the `<head>` which I of course have.

The site is hosted on Heroku.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your markup just with the icon and other content removed. Works in Codepen and others. What do you see when you load the URL for the icons in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check CDN url correctly?

I accidently put "http" instead of "https" and pushed it to Heroku, same thing happens as you.
After changing protocol to "https", it works fine.